# angular formio render with custom component

Tags: angular, formio

I have created a custom component using [FormIo](https://github.com/merobal/angular-formio-custom-demo/commit/e1522a6dae006b8994ec79deddcaf010c2b11fd2),
this is working fine, and I have saved that custom component in Database,

I have another project to render that component. I have tried to render that component but it was saying

`Unknown component: myrating`

do I need to add anything?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have old formio bundle without new changes on another project side. Thats why formio can't figure out how to render new component.